# Reading values from CSV files and storing in local variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, sftp, winscp

I am stuck at one point, the requirement is I have to store the Username, Password, Hostname & hostkey in a CSV file and I have to read & store the values in local variable which can be used for establishing SFTP connection.

My CSV looks like this:

```
HostName,Username,Password,SshHostKeyFingerprint
abc.com,Lear,qwert,ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx...
```

The code which I am using to read and store the different columns values is:

```
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

$csv = Import-Csv c:\test\output.csv
$csv | ForEach-Object
{
    $Hostname = $_.hostname
    $username = $_.username
    $Password = $_.Password
    "$Hostname - $username -$Password"
}

# Set up session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = $Hostname
    UserName = $username
    Password = $Password
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
}
```

Nothing is getting displayed, when trying to display the values.

Comment: For general security reasons, you cannot just pipe a plain text password to WinSCP (or any other Microsoft application). You will need to create a credentials (`New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential`) by using a secured password (`ConvertTo-SecureString -String "something" -AsPlainText -Force`), see e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41548976/1701026

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script block after the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet has to start on the same line. Otherwise PowerShell won't connect them together.

```
$csv | ForEach-Object {
    $HostName = $_.HostName
    $Username = $_.Username 
    $Password = $_.Password
    "$HostName - $Username - $Password"
}
```

---

Another problem, that your will face eventually, is that your code does process only the last line in the CSV file.

You most probably actually want to process the parsed out values *within* the `ForEach-Object` script block. Like this:

```
$csv | ForEach-Object {
    $HostName = $_.HostName
    $Username = $_.Username 
    $Password = $_.Password

    "$HostName - $Username - $Password"

    # Set up session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
        Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
        HostName = $HostName
        UserName = $Username
        Password = $Password
        SshHostKeyFingerprint = ...
    }

    # ...
}
```

Comment: At the time when we are importing the CSV from local machine following error is coming:        Import-Csv : Cannot bind parameter 'Delimiter'. Cannot convert value `"Integration\Scripts\Power" to type "System.Char". Error: "String must be exactly one 
character long."`

Comment: This is  the actual path: `# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"


$csv = Import-Csv C:\abc\Projects\Bank\Attendance Integration\Scripts\Power Shell Script\Configuration.csv
$csv | foreach-object {
    $Hostname = $_.hostname
    $username =$_.username
    $Password = $_.Password

    "$Hostname - $username -$Password"
  
    }

    $session.Dispose()`

Comment: You have to enclose the path with spaces to quotes: `$csv = Import-Csv "C:\abc\Projects\Bank\Attendance Integration\Scripts\Power Shell Script\Configuration.csv"`

Comment: Hi, One more error is coming in the code: 
`$csv = Import-Csv "C:\abc\Projects\Bank\Attendance Integration\Scripts\Power Shell Script\Configuration.csv"
$csv | foreach-object {
    $Hostname = $_.hostname
    $username =$_.username
    $Password = $_.Password
    $hostkey = $_.hostkey
 
    }
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = $Hostname
    UserName = $username
    Password = $Password
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = $hostkey
}`

Comment: The error which is coming is: `New-Object : The value supplied is not valid, or the property is read-only. Change the value, and then try again.
At C:\abc\Projects\Bank\Attendance Integration\Scripts\Power Shell Script\Download&MoveToArchive.ps1:16 char:19`

Comment: i have dummy value in CSV for fingerprint.

Comment: So put a real value there. `ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx...` is not valid fingerprint, let only the actual fingerprint of your host key. See [Where do I get SSH host key fingerprint to authorize the server?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey)